# How to get traefik ingress to load balance across several ClusterIP services

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I want to be able to load balance several nodes of a backend service represented by `ClusterIP` services using a `traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1` ingress. I know that `ClusterIP` service can load balance easily with deployments and `ReplicaSet`  but the way this application is designed each node needs to be it's own Deployment as it is a stateful node.

So I either need a way to have the flow be:

```
Ingress --> [ClusterIP-Node1, ClusterIP-Node2, ClusterIP-Node3, ClusterIP-Node4]
```

or

```
Ingress --> ClusterIP-LoadBalancer --> [ClusterIP-Node1, ClusterIP-Node2, ClusterIP-Node3, ClusterIP-Node4]
```

How can I use `traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1` to automatically loadbalance between these `ClusterIP` services?

For example, if I currently have one `Ingress` for each `ClusterIP, like this:

```
...
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: my-service-node1-ingress
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`myservice-node1.mycompany.example`)
      services:
        - kind: Service
          name: myservice-node1-clusterip
          passHostHeader: true
          port: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice-node1-clusterip
  labels:
    app: myservice
    tier: backend
    name: myservice-node1
spec:
  selector:
    app: myservice
    tier: backend
    name: myservice-node1-deployment
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: rpc-listener
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8545
... N+1
```

And I want to change that to a single `Ingress` Point similar to this:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: my-service-ingress
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`myservice.mycompany.example`)
      services:
        - kind: Service
          name: myservice-node1-clusterip
          passHostHeader: true
          port: 80
```

Is it possible to have the `traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1` load balance across the services similar to this? I saw something that looked promising on this page in the [docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.1/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/) that you can have `n` number of `services[n].name` for a matching route `routes[n].services`. Does that mean you can do something similar to the following?

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: my-service-ingress
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`myservice.mycompany.example`)
      services:
        - kind: Service
          name: myservice-node1-clusterip
          passHostHeader: true
          port: 80
        - kind: Service
          name: myservice-node2-clusterip
          passHostHeader: true
          port: 80
        - kind: Service
          name: myservice-node3-clusterip
          passHostHeader: true
          port: 80
        - kind: Service
          name: myservice-node4-clusterip
          passHostHeader: true
          port: 80
```

Also, is there a way to pass the `sessionAffinity` with it like there are in services `sessionAffinity: ClientIP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample I posted initially works as is:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: my-service-ingress
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`myservice.mycompany.example`)
      services:
        - kind: Service
          name: myservice-node1-clusterip
          passHostHeader: true
          port: 80
        - kind: Service
          name: myservice-node2-clusterip
          passHostHeader: true
          port: 80
        - kind: Service
          name: myservice-node3-clusterip
          passHostHeader: true
          port: 80
        - kind: Service
          name: myservice-node4-clusterip
          passHostHeader: true
          port: 80
```